# JdbcTemplate does not support Parameterized Query 'IN' case? Must by NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, sql, spring, db2

Aimed at preventing SQL injection attacks, all the SQL Statement code in my project should transformed to Parameterized Query. But I got a problem when the query condition includes a 'IN' case. Like this (Using DB2 database):

```
String employeeId = 'D2309';
String name = "%brady%";

List<Integer> userRights = new ArrayList<Integer>();
userRights.add(1);
userRights.add(2);
userRights.add(3);

String sql = "SELECT * FROM T_EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = ? AND NAME LIKE ? 
AND RIGHT IN (?)";

jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[] {employeeId, name, userRights}, new 
EmployeeRowMapper());
```

The above code runs failed with the exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad 
SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM T_EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = ? AND NAME LIKE ? AND 
RIGHT IN (?)]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io: [jcc][1091][10824]
[3.57.82] .... ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
```

The question here is that does not JdbcTemplate support Parameterized Query for IN case? and I know this work can be done by NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, and whether only NamedParameterJdbcTemplate can do IN case query?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not a problem with Spring's JDBC Template. Instead it is a general JDBC related issue (java.sql). AFAIK, there is no solution for this... (+1; good question, we may find someone providing a solution).

Comment: Btw: the only way I got `IN` to work is by dynamically building the query string, e.g. `IN (?, ?, ?) ` and then adding each value of the list explicitly to the Object[] array.

Comment: Maybe it works, but it requires much more code and efforts to generate condition string for IN case. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comments, I'm not happy with this solution as it dynamically generates a number of SQL statements. Given the number of `userRights` is between 1 and n, it requires up to n prepared statements in the cache.

The below should work (I did not try it).

```
String employeeId = 'D2309';
String name = "%brady%";

List<Integer> userRights = new ArrayList<Integer>();
userRights.add(1);
userRights.add(2);
userRights.add(3);

// build the input string
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < userRights.size; i++) {
    sb.append("?");
    if (i < userRights.size() - 1) {
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}

// build the SQL
String sql = "SELECT * FROM T_EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = ?" +
    " AND NAME LIKE ?" +
    " AND RIGHT IN (" + sb.toString() + ")";

// init the object array
// size is employeeId + name + right
Object[] param = new Object[2 + userRights.size()];

// fill it
param[0] = employeeId;
param[1] = name;

for (int i = 0; i < userRights.size(); i++) {
    param[i + 2] = userRights.get(i);
}

jdbcTemplate.query(sql, param, new EmployeeRowMapper());
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated for your useful answer. You solution works very well, but I think it's hard to be designed in common. I intend to make all SQL-related handling methods into a single Utility class. And I don't know what is performance of it?

Comment: Hm, hard to say regarding performance... you can further optimize it by combining the two for loops into one as they both iterate over `userRights`. It might be much more efficient to read all user rights for a given person, cache them in e.g. a session, and then compare against the in-memory list...

Comment: Thanks! I prefer to use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to reach my goal. Clearly, it does not make sense that write so much code to merge a sql string.　～～　haha

Comment: I agree, that's what I meant :-)